# How to share state between threads in Flask when one route is streaming using while loop and another is open for getting params from the client?

Tags: python, flask, python-multithreading

I have a flask application, that stream a a camera data to a web browser.
I want be able to send params via ajax from the browser, and set up video settings.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, Response
from camera import VideoCamera

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

def gen(camera):
    while True:
        frame = camera.get_frame()
        yield (b'--frame\r\n'
               b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n\r\n')

@app.route('/video_feed')
def video_feed():
    return Response(gen(VideoCamera()),
                    mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=False, processes=2)
```

As you can see, gen function has a while loop, that streams video once called.
I also set up a processes=2, in order to let Flask receive other request from the browser, and prevent while loop from blocking the server.

Now I want to add another route, that will get POST ajax requests from the browser (input value) and path the value to get_frame() inside `while True`

Comment: Your `flask` app is not `multi-threaded`, it is running multiple processes. To make it multi-threaded, use:

    `app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=False, threaded=True)`

To share state between threads, you can use a `global` variable or throw it in http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/api/#flask.g

Comment: @NehalJ.Wani Tried, it stuck the server, and I have to kill the process.